# CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, salesforce

I'm trying to load a table from Salesforce into BigQuery, but when I try to change a field that is a timestamp field from a string to a timestamp, it fails. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Things I've tried to narrow down the problem
If I load 200k records and treat all fields as a string: data loads
If I just load 200k records of that single timestamp field as a timestamp: data loads
If I load 30 records of all fields and treat all fields as string, but keep that timestamp field as a timestamp: data loads
If I load all 200k records of all fields and treat all fields as string, but keep that timestamp field as a timestamp: fails with error "CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up"

I tried to single out what the issue is, but I'm failing at figuring out what is going on.
the timestamp is for sure a timestamp that is computer generated by Salesforce with 0 nulls.

```
import pandas as pd
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas


username = xxxx
password = xxxx
token = xxxx
instance = xxxx



sf_object = xxxx
table = xxx
query = xxxx
columns = xxxx
schema_list = [xxxxx]
    


    sf = Salesforce(username= username,
                password=password,
                security_token=token,
                instance_url = instance)

    Final_data = []
   


    SFquery = (query)
    response=sf.query_all(SFquery)

    ##formating the table for BQ##
    for i in response['records']:
        print(i)

    df=pd.DataFrame(response['records']).drop(['attributes'], axis=1)
    df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
    pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr',True)
    Pre_final = df.values.tolist()
    Final_data = Final_data + Pre_final
   
  



        # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()

    # TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
    table_id = table+sf_object

    dataframe_load = columns


    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
        Final_data,
        columns=
            dataframe_load                  
                ,
    )    

#
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
       
        schema = schema_list,
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
 )

    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.
    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

    table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print(
        "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
            table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
        )
    )
```

Comment: I've tried something else. the dtype are all object.

if I save it to CSV and then upload it to BQ, it actually works. 

I noticed that when I look at the dtype in the csv file, they are all float64. 

I tried to convert all fields from object to float, but says it can't convert a str to a float